# Temporarily stop Log shipping

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, log-shipping

How can I temporarily stop log shipping --> Do the task --> Start the Log shipping ? Is it possible ?

Comment: Are you doing the 'task' on the target or the source instance? What is the task? We need more details on the configuration of your log shipping setup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes simple way to temporarily stop Logshipping is to disable all the jobs related to Logshipping, since LS is basically backup of transaction logs and restore you have control over it. You need to disable Backup, copy and restore jobs. Please also make sure you disable LS_Alert jobs because they would fire and unnecessarily give you false alerts.

**Caution:**

If you stop the jobs for longer duration your database recovery stands exposed so be careful with that.

You also should keep in mind that the transaction log backup which would be done after you start the job might be big in size and it would take time to copy it and restore it. If the size is too big you might get some out of sync alerts so be ready for it.

Comment: I would only stop `copy` and/or `restore` jobs with their related alerts (stopping restore job should be enough though) if possible. And I would leave `transaction log backup` job working.
That depends a lot on what You want to do within that downtime. Work on publisher? Or on subscriber?
Subscriber server shouldn't have problems with catching up after starting `restore` job again (but it might take a long time till the end of process, depending on downtime length and backup volumes).